# What does reclass function in xts package do?

Tags: r, xts

I thought it was for turning a xts object to its original class, but after I pass an xts object into it, it did not give me the original object back. What does it for?

My attempt

```
data(sample_matrix)
class(sample_matrix)
#"matrix"
class(reclass(as.xts(sample_matrix)))
#"xts" "zoo"
```

Comment: Try `Reclass` not `reclass` to get a matrix again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs

> **try.xts** and **reclass** are functions that enable external developers
>   access to the reclassing tools within xts to help speed development of
>   time-aware functions, as well as provide a more robust and seemless
>   end-user experience, regardless of the end-user's choice of
>   data-classes.

if you use `try.xts` to convert a `xtsible` object to `xts` object , `reclass` or `Reclass` both should be able to convert it back to it's original class with all attributes intact.

```
class(Reclass(try.xts(sample_matrix)))
## [1] "matrix"

class(reclass(try.xts(sample_matrix)))
## [1] "matrix"
```

Comment: What does try.xts do? It coerce an object to xts, while the same time preserve all the necessary information needed to coerce it back to original class, am I right? I have read the official docs, but sorry I cann't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

A call to `reclass` returns the object to its original class, with all original attributes intact - unless otherwise changed.

From the docs:

> Reclass is designed for top-level use, where it is desirable to have
>   the object returned from an arbitrary function in the same class as
>   the object passed in. Most functions within R are not designed to
>   return objects matching the original object’s class. While this tool
>   is highly experimental at present, it attempts to handle conversion
>   and reconversion transparently. The caveats are that the original
>   object must be coercible to xts, the returned object must be of the
>   same row length as the original object, and that the object to
>   reconvert to is the ﬁrst argument to the function being wrapped.

Comment: Do you know how to use it? I have viewed the docs, but I have no clue.

Comment: @user3226059:- Check this doc it has the usage as well:- http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xts/xts.pdf